# Prepositional madness! Of, or in?

Tags: prepositions

This has been bothering me for the last day or so.

Would you say:

> "I have a mind to send him a strongly-worded letter, just to see if he can read five words **of** it."

Or:

> "I have a mind to send him a strongly-worded letter, just to see if he can read five words **in** it."

Personally, I am leaning toward "of," but have come here to see if others agree with me. Thanks!

Comment: _Five words of it_ seems to refer to 5 words in sequence, while _five words in it_ simply means 'choose any 5 words contained in it'. If it was ***the*** _five words_, however, it wouldn't matter which preposition was used, because that means there are only 5 words in the letter.

Comment: Hmm, well, I was trying to convey the fact that this person is probably not able to read. Would you suggest "in," then?

Comment: Why bother with counting? ", just to see if he can read it."

Comment: Good point! The only reason I bring this up is that my friend said this yesterday in reference to Floyd Mayweather's literacy skills. He specifically said the "five words" part in order to emphasize that Floyd can probably read two-letter words and nothing more.

Comment: You're trying to put too much condescending information into one sneer.

Comment: Not I, good sir! I completely agree with you, but that is beside the point, no?

Comment: @Matt The preposition frames the metaphor. If you say "in", you're framing the letter as a *container* for the letter; if you say *of*, you're framing the letter as *being composed of* its words. The former treats the letter as the physical object, the piece of paper carrying the words communicating your message. The latter treats the letter as  abstract message you're sending, the thoughts you're communicating, and the physical object as merely the vehicle conveying it (and, e.g. if you had sent it via email, the "letter" would be the same). Because that's how I conceive of it, I prefer *of*.

Comment: Thanks, Dan! That was extremely helpful, and well explained! :)

Comment: @DanBron that's an detailed meaningful explanation. An alternate, just as good explanation is that in that context  English speakers would idiomatically just tend to say 'of it'.

Comment: One sneer doth not the sum of condescending information make.

Comment: To me, "five words of it" would suggest _the first five words_, whereas, as John Lawler pointed out, "five words in it" implies _any five words in it_.

Answer (score 1):

The intent of your communication is important.

If you say "...five words of it." you feel that the recipient is an imbecile who doesn't "get" the big picture. "I received your letter.  What part of the situation do you feel I don't understand?"

If you say "...five words in it." you feel that the recipient is not educated.  "I received your letter ma'am.  Which five words do you suppose I am incapable of understanding?"

This might be a bit obscure, but think of Polonius from Hamlet.  He's a "five words of it" kinda guy, not a "five words in it," kinda guy.

Answer (score 0):

I also lean towards "of", but I would say that both are acceptable.

You can look at "of" as a possessive:

> the letter's words --> the words of the letter